# Delete currently selected item from QTreeWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

Im working with a Qt GUI application, and i have a QTreeWidget with values. 
I have added each value to the tree like so:

```
QTreeWidgetItem *node = new QTreeWidgetItem();
node->setText(0, m_stringList[i];
node->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsSelectable | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemisDragEnabled);
ui->sourceTreeWidget->addTopLevelItem(node);
```

What i am trying to implement now, is a delete button to allow the user to select one or multiple tree items by clicking them, and then pressing the delete button.

The button part is easy.

The part i need some help with, is finding out how to retrieve the string/text value of the currently selected tree item(s).

Anyone have some tips or hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly is your problem with that? You create a `SLOT` for the button and retrieve a list of the selected items with

```
QList<QTreeWidgetItem*> sel_items = ui->sourceTreeWidget->selectedItems();
for(int i=0; i<sel_items.size(); i++){
    ...
}
```

[as stated in the documentation for QTreeWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#selectedItems). You may then iterate through the list and delete them directly or simply retrieve `the string/text value` as you asked.